# ¿Como instalar C# en SublimeText?

Tags: c#, sublimetext3, sublimetext

El problema es que actualmente quiero programar sobre esta tecnologia, pero no quiero descargar aun el visual studio porque consume recursos y es bastante pesado, asi que quiero iniciar de manera sencilla pero efectiva en sublime text y me gustaria saber como se hace porque me sale error al tratar de instalar dicho lenguaje, si es que se le puede llamar asi al proceso.

Este el archivo que clone de un github y que tenia que poner para que me pudiera compilar programas de tipo .cs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el pequeño archivo que quisiera ejecutar con c#
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el error que me sale al ejecutar "build" que es lo que hace que se ejecute el programa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya esta escogido c# como el lenguaje por default de build

Comment: Prueba instalando .Net core y usando el comando **dotnet run** en el folder donde esta el codigo.

Comment: De hecho desde la pagina de descarga puedes ver como iniciar https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es instalar el compilador de C# y Omnisharp para Sumblime para que tengas el autocompletado y resaltado de sintaxis.

### Compilador de C# y .NET

Si quieres una version de .NET ligera con la que practicar el lenguaje puedes instalar .NET Core, asi compilarias simplemente usando el comando:

```
$> dotnet build
```

**Referencia:** https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows

### Omnisharp para Sublime

Usando el **Package Control**, instala el paquete llamado **OmniSharp**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/), es una excelente herramienta para aprender C#, no tiene auto completado si no utilizas la versión premium, pero aún en su versión gratuita es excelente.